# Floating a sidebar into the margin with ConTeXt

Tags: floats, context

I would like to use `\framedtext` to create a grey sidebar that floats to the right of the text.

While I've discovered framedtext, I haven't figured out how to place it such that it floats with text wrapping and without a caption. I suspect that some theme on placeframedtext will be necessary.

Here's what I have so far:

```
\setupframedtexts[bodyfont=small, location=right hanging, width=3 cm]

\framedtext{
In this section, the steps towards creating a \SDFN\ will be described in the main text, while specific examples from my experience will be revealed in sidebars like this one. These will be reflective on the lessons I learned while creating the \SDFN\ in contract with the prescriptive tone of the main text. }
```

I suspect my arguments to location are lacking.

Edit: There's a suggestion that flowing places is possible from "starthangingaround" but it's an undocumented feature...

Comment: Have you seen Chapter 5 of the [Details](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/details.pdf) manual? It gives explicit examples of floating figures in the margin. The same idea will work for a `\framedtext` instead of a `\externalfigure`.

Comment: The problem is *spanning* the margin and body, not just placing a framedtext in there.

Comment: The details manual gives examples for spanning the figure in the margin and body. See page 34 and 38.

Comment: Thanks. If you throw that up as an answer, I'll accept it. It's exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for not being thinky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See page 34 and 38 of the [Details](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/details.pdf) manual.

Answer (score 3):

Based on advice from @Aditya, I looked at: Pages 34-38 of the [Details](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/details.pdf) manual.

On MkIV (using the `context` command), the following code creates a margin-spanning grayed sidebar on the outer edge of the page:

```
\starttext

\definefloat
    [marginfigure]

\setupfloats
    [sidespacebefore=none,
     sidespaceafter=depth]

\setupfloat
    [marginfigure]
    [criterium=.5\textwidth,
     maxwidth=\rightmarginwidth,
     default={outermargin,none}]

\setupframedtexts[background=screen, 
    corner=round, 
    width=7cm,
    style={\setupbodyfont[10pt]}]

\placemarginfigure{} {\framedtext{In this section, the steps towards creating a SDFN will be described in the main text, while specific examples from my experience will be revealed in sidebars like this one. These will be reflective on the lessons I learned while creating the SDFN in contract with the prescriptive tone of the main text. }}

This section will describe the process of creating a SDFN in full. It is intended as a descriptive manual to provide readers with a way to run the methodology for themselves. In brief, the SDFN begins through the explanation of terms, a summary of the ideas expressed above. If participants do not understand the nature of entities, an entity dictionary should be created. When participants understand entity and flow, a topic is chosen and the diagram is created. 

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 0):

have you played with the `inmargin` command? http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Reference/en/inmargin

sounds like what you want...